# When does node.js clear or remove items from the "require" cache?

Tags: node.js, caching

I read that when you `require` a file, node.js reads the file from disk only the first time, and after that caches it.

When are items removed from the cache ? If I `require` 1000's of different files (each only once, within a methods scope), then can my server run out of memory (because of the cache), or does the cache have a fixed size, after which it removes items from the cache ?

```
function foo(var bar){

    var shoe;
    if (bar === "blue"){
        shoe = require("./somefile.js");
    }else if (bar === "red"){
        shoe = require ("./someotherfile.js"){
    } //.....etc m

    //Do something with shoe etc...

}
```

I ask because, I have many different files stored as JSON, and using `require` is more convenient than using `fs` to create the object.

Comment: Once a piece of Javascript is loaded into memory, it stays in memory for duration of that node.js process.  It never goes away.  The cache is just a small reference to the module that was previously loaded.  If you are indeed doing `require()` on thousands of files, that will take more and more memory, but not because of the cache - but because of the additional code you are loading each time you `require()` a module that hasn't previously been loaded.  The cache prevents it from getting loaded again if you request the same module that has already been loaded.

Comment: @jfriend00 So are you saying that the cache will keep growing indefinitely (until I run out of memory). But I assume I can explicitly delete the item from the cache?

Comment: The cache is a very small amount of memory.  It just retains some metadata about each loaded module.  The lion's share of the memory is used by the module itself.  I don't know of any way to "unrequire" a module or to modify the cache.  I don't know why you'd focus on the cache at all.  That would not be your issue if you were running low on memory.

Comment: I would have to unload the module if If I was running low on memory.

Comment: Related answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676612/unloading-code-modules and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682104/release-required-module-from-node-js and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/I26CN95d_JM